# Vue warn, Failed to generate render function

Tags: laravel, vue.js

While console logging an array passed from blade to vue I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctPIB.png).

In index.blade I have this

```
<books :books="{{ $books }}"></books>
```

And my Books.vue is

```
<template>
    <!-- <tbody class="tbody">
        <book-row v-for="book in books" :key="book.id"></book-row>
    </tbody> -->
</template>

<script>
import BookRow from './BookRow.vue';

export default {
    props: ['books'],
    components: {BookRow},
    data() {
        return {

        }
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log(this.books);
    },
}
```

What is the problem?
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

in your blade file remove `:`
`<books books="{{ $books }}"></books>`

But, instead of using the above method i would suggest you to use axios or fetch inside vue. Get data via api.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
Removing `:` didn't help, because in that case no data is binded to my vue object, I mean console logging books in `mounted()` prints just blank data.
I haven't used axios ever, but yeah I think I should start using it.

Comment: you are partially right, but inside blade file `:` this is of no use. vue binding are specifically within js files. try to console inside created instead of mounted.